# Double scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I have this **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qrsotzpr/2/)** with a parallax effect on my images. 
The problem is that I have two scrollbars in the result. 
How can I have only one scrollbar for all my content ?

HTML :

```
<div id="intro">
<p>Sed uelit, sed quia...</p>
</div>

<div id="text">
<h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <section id="frame1">
        <div class="back">
        </div>
    </section>


        <section id="frame7">
        <div class="back">

        </div>
    </section>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but my div id="text" won't be fixing : https://jsfiddle.net/qrsotzpr/12/

Answer (score 0):

The second scrollbar is showing up because of the default box-model behavior on `#wrapper` and it's 3px border. To address that, you can assign `box-sizing:border-box;` to `#wrapper` and the border will be constrained within `#wrapper`. https://jsfiddle.net/qrsotzpr/9/

Comment: @user3870112 the fiddle doesn't work for you? I'm only seeing a single scrollbar.

Comment: Yes, when you scroll at the bottom of the page, you can see two scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

You could use `overflow: hidden;` on`body`, live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/k5zwqvjd/

> The overflow property specifies whether to clip content, render
>   scrollbars or just display content when it overflows its block level
>   container.

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes but where are my other div and my parallax effect ?

Comment: @user3870112 thanks for comment, I have edited my answer, just apply overflow: hidden on body, please have a look at let me know if it solves your issue. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that I need the body overflow :/

Answer (score 0):

> You could use overflow: hidden; in #wrapper

```
#wrapper {

      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      height: 100%;
      perspective: 1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border:3px solid cyan;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;

    }
```